# Possible Mistake in Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, big-o-notation

In Skiena's book *Algorithm Design Manual, 3rd Edition*, it is claimed on page 45 that

$$
mn - m^2 + m \in \Omega(mn)
$$

where $m,n \geq 0$ and $m \leq n$. I claim that this is in fact false, with the following proof. Toward a contradiction, suppose otherwise. Then $$mn-m^2 + m \geq cmn$$ where $m,n > N_{0}$ for some sufficiently large interger $N_{0}$ and some constant $c > 0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $c < 1$ since the RHS above is a lower bound. Then after some rearrangement and canceling terms, we obtain

$$
1-c \geq \frac{m-1}{n}.
$$

Now recall we can take $m = n$, so we obtain

$$
1-c \geq \frac{n-1}{n},
$$

where the RHS is not greater than $1$. However it is easy to see that $\frac{n-1}{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, given any fixed constant $0 < c < 1$, we will be unable to choose a sufficiently large bound $N_{0}$ such that when $m,n > N_{0}$ the above inequality is satisfied. Thus the original claim is false.

In fact, the claim is apparently still false even under the stronger assumption that $m - a \leq n$ for some constant $a > 0$. In this case we arrive at the final inequality

$$
1-c \geq \frac{n-a+1}{n},
$$

where the RHS still converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Question:** Where did I go wrong above? Did I go wrong above? I would appreciate any feedback addressing any issue with the argument above.

**P.S.** There exists at least [one question](/q/134542/%CE%A9fx-and-worst-case-analysis) on here that also references this equation in the text but the discussion there does not address this particular issue with the claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are totally right, though I think there is an easier proof: if $m = n$, then $mn-m^2 +m= m\notin \Omega(m^2)$.

However, since the analysis is done when searching for a worst case, you could just add a condition $2m\leqslant n$ for the analysis to be correct.

But there is indeed a mistake in the analysis by Skiena, that could be clarified.

Comment: Aha!  That of course is a much simpler analysis...  Many thanks.